# Laravel spaces in url

Tags: laravel-4

I am using Laravel as the framework for an api resource server.

I have a url

```
http://www.local.dev/method1?parameter1=2014-06-25&parameter2=0&parameter3=313&parameter4=TEST%20233&parameter5=02-04
```

However it keeps giving me an error which paramter5 is not defined. Value of parameter 4 is actually "TEST 233" with a space in between. How do I handle the space or the encoded space on the api server side from the url?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the input parameters?

It works on my side with the following code in my controller:

```
// Either \Input or just Input
$inputs = Input::only('parameter4', 'parameter5');
print_r($inputs);
```

And this code in my routing:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $testParam = new Namespace\ControllerName;
    $testParam->index();
});
```

My URL looks like:

```
http://dev.local/?parameter1=2014-06-25&parameter2=0&parameter3=313&parameter4=TEST%20233&parameter5=02-04
```